# How to write data to appsettings.json in a console application (.net Core)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

To read data from `appsettings.json` I use`ConfigurationBuilder`, `ConfigurationBinder`.
 
 `ConfigurationBuilder`,`ConfigurationBinder` allow you to read data from `appsettings.json`.

**Questions:**
 - How to write data to `appsettings.json` in a console application?
Can I write data to `appsettings.json` using`ConfigurationBuilder`, `ConfigurationBinder`?
Or do I need to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Settings> (fileText)` to write data to `appsettings.json`?
In other words, if you use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, then I should:
 - read the data `appsettings.json`;
- change the data in the desired
   section;
- save the data in `appsettings.json`.

Do I understand the logic of working with `appsettings.json`?

**Picture-1**
 [image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

Code **AppSettings.cs**

```
namespace ConsoleAppCore
{
    class AppSettings
    {
        public string KeyA_SecMain { get; set; }
        public string KeyB_SecMain { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Code **appsettings.json**

```
   {
  "SectionMain": {
    "KeyA_SecMain": "KeyA_SecMain_Value",
    "KeyB_SecMain": "KeyB_SecMain_Value"
  }
}
```

Code **ReadWriteAppSettings.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;           
using System.IO;                                    

namespace ConsoleAppCore
{
    class ReadWriteAppSettings
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Read GetSection AppSettings
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string ReadGetSectionAppSettings()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            string result = configuration.GetSection("SectionMain:KeyA_SecMain").Value;

            return result;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Bind AppSettings
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void BindAppSettings()
        {
            AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            var configuration = builder.Build();

            var configurationResult = configuration.GetSection("SectionMain");

            ConfigurationBinder.Bind(configurationResult, appSettings);

            string result_KeyA_Sec1 = appSettings.KeyA_SecMain;
            string result_KeyB_Sec1 = appSettings.KeyB_SecMain;            
        }        
    }
}
```

Code **Program.cs**

```
namespace ConsoleAppCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            ReadGetSectionAppSettings();
            BindAppSettings();            
        }        

        static public string ReadGetSectionAppSettings()
        {
            ReadWriteAppSettings readWriteAppSettings = new ReadWriteAppSettings();
            string str = readWriteAppSettings.ReadGetSectionAppSettings();

            return str;
        }

        static public void BindAppSettings()
        {
            ReadWriteAppSettings readWriteAppSettings = new ReadWriteAppSettings();
            readWriteAppSettings.BindAppSettings();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is no need to write to the file itself, what is your need? You know that there is also an option to set ```IConfiguration``` in memory: ```.AddInMemoryCollection()```. For example on startup set the values by code and everywhere else just use the ```IConfiguration``` (pay attention to the registered configuration providers). [Do configuration in .net-core](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 9):

I use this helper class. Class writes setting to appsettings.json file in /bin folder. If you need another path just modify path to appsettings.json file.

```
public static class SettingsHelpers
{
    public static void AddOrUpdateAppSetting<T>(string sectionPathKey, T value)
    {
        try
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json");
            string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            SetValueRecursively(sectionPathKey, jsonObj, value);

            string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error writing app settings | {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void SetValueRecursively<T>(string sectionPathKey, dynamic jsonObj, T value)
    {
        // split the string at the first ':' character
        var remainingSections = sectionPathKey.Split(":", 2);

        var currentSection = remainingSections[0];
        if (remainingSections.Length > 1)
        {
            // continue with the procress, moving down the tree
            var nextSection = remainingSections[1];
            SetValueRecursively(nextSection, jsonObj[currentSection], value);
        }
        else
        {
            // we've got to the end of the tree, set the value
            jsonObj[currentSection] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
 SettingsHelpers.AddOrUpdateAppSetting<int>("Page", 5);
```